# How can I get clang-format to put the parameters of a brace-initialized construction on the same line?

Tags: c++, clang-format

I'm running `clang-format`, with a `.clang-format` file which only specifies `Language: Cpp`, on this input (invalid C++, but that's unimportant for this):

```cpp
const auto SOME_VARIABLE_NAME = {{"key", { {"key2", std::array{ 0, 0, 0, 0, }}, }}};
```

I get this output:

```cpp
const auto SOME_VARIABLE_NAME = {{"key",
                                  {
                                      {"key2",
                                       std::array{
                                           0,
                                           0,
                                           0,
                                           0,
                                       }},
                                  }}};
```

I would something closer to the following output:

```cpp
const auto SOME_VARIABLE_NAME = {{"key",
                                  {
                                      {"key2",
                                       std::array{0, 0, 0, 0}},
                                  }}};
```

I am not sure why clang-format puts a line break after each `0`, around column 50.

What setting should I add to my `.clang-format` to achieve this?

I've tried a few specifiers that I thought might be relevant, to no avail:

- `AllowAllParametersOfDeclarationOnNextLine: true`
- `AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine: true`
- `BinPackParameters: true`
- `BreakBeforeBinaryOperators: false`
- `ColumnLimit: 120`
- `ConstructorInitializerAllOnOneLineOrOnePerLine: true`
- `Cpp11BracedListStyle: false`
- `IndentFunctionDeclarationAfterType: true`
- `PenaltyBreakBeforeFirstCallParameter: 1000`
- `Standard: Cpp11`

Edit: Still have this problem. Added a comment after the first brace to at least force the braces to the left more:

```cpp
const auto SOME_VARIABLE_NAME = {  //
    {"key",
     {
         {"key2",
          std::array{
              0,
              0,
              0,
              0,
          }},
     }}};
```

Comment: *"invalid C++, but that's unimportant for this"*. Actually, clang-format can do some pretty bizzare things with invalid code. Try it with valid code first.

Comment: I ran into this problem with valid code using a brace-initialized json object from https://github.com/nlohmann/json. I simplified it for this question, but I'll edit to use valid code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with the trailing comma immediately before the closing brace. The trailing comma (which is optional in `c++`) tells `clang-format` to put each element on a separate line. I don't know where this convention comes from, and it does not seem to be [documented](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html). In your case, it seems to be getting in the way.

If you remove just the comma after the last "0", the default `clang-format` settings produce this:

```
const auto SOME_VARIABLE_NAME = {{"key",
                                  {
                                      {"key2", std::array{0, 0, 0, 0}},
                                  }}};
```

...which is not quite what you were asking for, but is fairly close.